# How can I have multiple Identity user types when using ASP.NET Core Identity and Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I have two types of users within my application, `Customers` and `Professionals`. I'm using ASP.NET Identity to manage my users. Currently I have only a single user of type `ApplicationUser` and use flags to differentiate between `Customers` and `Professionals`.

However this approach seems rather messy to me. So I'm trying to to store identity related information on the Identity Framework default table, `Customer` related information in a `Customers` table and `Professional` related information on a `Professionals` table.

These are my new user entities on my domain:

```
public class Account : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
    public string FullName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public bool HasAcceptedTermsOfUse { get; set; } = default;
}

public class Customer : Account
{
    // Customer specific properties
}

public class Professional : Account
{
    // Professional specific properties
}
```

This is my modified `DbContext` to support both `Customers` and `Professionals`:

```
public class XenDbContext: IdentityDbContext<Account, IdentityRole<Guid>, Guid>
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Professional> Professionals { get; set; }
    // Other DbSets

    public XenDbContext(DbContextOptions<XenDbContext> options) 
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.Entity<Account>(entity => { entity.ToTable("Accounts"); });
        builder.Entity<Customer>(entity => { entity.ToTable("Customers"); });
        builder.Entity<Professional>(entity => { entity.ToTable("Professionals"); });
        builder.Entity<IdentityRole<Guid>>(entity => { entity.ToTable("Roles"); });
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<Guid>>(entity => { entity.ToTable("AccountRoles"); });
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<Guid>>(entity => { entity.ToTable("AccountClaims"); });
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<Guid>>(entity => { entity.ToTable("AccountLogins"); });
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<Guid>>(entity => { entity.ToTable("AccountTokens"); });
        builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<Guid>>(entity => { entity.ToTable("RoleClaims"); });
    }
}
```

I'm able to run `Add-Migration` and `Update-Database` with this structure. However when I run my API I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException
> HResult=0x80131509
> Message=Scheme already exists: Identity.Application
> Source=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions
>
> StackTrace:
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationOptions.AddScheme(String name, Action`1 configureBuilder)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`2.b__0(AuthenticationOptions o)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigureNamedOptions`1.Configure(String name, TOptions options) at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.UnnamedOptionsManager`1.get_Value() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationSchemeProvider..ctor(IOptions`1 options, IDictionary`2 schemes) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationSchemeProvider..ctor(IOptions`1 options)
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Span`1& arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions) at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType) at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.b__0(RequestDelegate next)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ApplicationBuilder.Build()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplicationBuilder.b__27_0(RequestDelegate next)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ApplicationBuilder.Build()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.d__37.MoveNext()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.d__12.MoveNext()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.d__4.MoveNext()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.d__4.MoveNext()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication.Run(String url)
> at Xen.Presentation.API.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Arthur\Development\Xen\src\backend\Presentation\Xen.Presentation.API\Program.cs:line 53

I don't understand a lot about Identity Framework but it seems like the problem arises when I have multiple `AddIdentity` calls.

This is my `PersistenceServiceRegistration` in my persistence layer:

```
public static class PersistenceServiceRegistration
{
    public static void AddPersistenceServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("XenDbLocalConnectionString");
        
        services.AddDbContext<XenDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

        services.AddIdentity<Account, IdentityRole<Guid>>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<XenDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddIdentity<Customer, IdentityRole<Guid>>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<XenDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddIdentity<Professional, IdentityRole<Guid>>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<XenDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // Register repositories
    }
}
```

In addition to `Professionals` and `Customers`, I have `AddIdentity` for `Account` because I want to be able to generate tokens for both `Customers` and `Professionals` via `Account`. This is my full [`PersistenceServiceRegistration.cs`](https://gist.github.com/ItsMeArthur/135afb513f009f4707b198550523c9c5) with the code I removed for brevity.

This is the `Program.cs` on my API:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        builder.Services.AddApplicationServices();

        builder.Services.AddPersistenceServices(builder.Configuration);

        builder.Services.AddInfrastructureServices(builder.Configuration);

        builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

        builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
        });

        builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("Open", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
        });

        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

        var app = builder.Build();
     
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlerMiddleware>();

        app.MapControllers();

        app.Run();
    }
}
```

One of the references I've used to implement this was [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49075076/2534489). I have also tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47434573/2534489) to work around the issue. I also gave [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58848481/2534489) a shot, but I'm not sure I understand it.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying? And if so, how can I achieve it?

**Edit:**

I managed to make it work by commenting out the `app.UseAuthorization()` method in `Program.cs`. However that's not a solution, since I need authentication and authorization.

Here [is a sample with the sample program on GitHub](https://github.com/ItsMeArthur/IdentityDemoAPI), if you run it you will run into the same problem.

Comment: [Inheritance is a bad way to model](https://boxbase.org/entries/2020/aug/3/case-against-oop/) human users of an application and subclases are mutually-exclusive. Consider, what if a user is both a Customer and a Professional-User at the same time? (Also, EF and ORMs in general don't work well when you use entity classes with inheritance (RDBMS don't have any easy-way to _prevent_ dependent rows existing in other tables, so your DB _could_ have data that your inheritance-based model considers invalid and impossible).

Comment: @Dai EF has good support for this kind of design. https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/inheritance#:~:text=Inheritance%20is%20a%20key%20object,%7B

Comment: @Neil Just because EF supports it doesn't mean it's actually a good idea to use it in an application.

Comment: EF supports it because it's a common enough pattern that lots of projects use.  Your arguments against it are unjustified  "EF and ORMs in general don't work well when you use entity classes with inheritance" - incorrect as the support is already there. "RDBMS don't have any easy-way to prevent dependent rows existing in other tables, so your DB could have data that your inheritance-based model considers invalid and impossible" - EF prevents this by providing proper support.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AddIdentity() fails "InvalidOperationException: Scheme already exists: Identity.Application"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51161729/addidentity-fails-invalidoperationexception-scheme-already-exists-identity)

Comment: @Neil sadly no. That was one the posts I had already tried.

Comment: @Dai will take a look into it, but at this point this is what I need to get it working. I guess at this point its too late to change the whole paradigm of the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. After a lot failure I finally managed to get it working. If you're having the same issue, this is how I managed to do it:

Simply replace `AddIdentity` with `AddIdentityCore`. From what I was able to gather reading the source code they are quite similar, but `AddIdentity` by default register some authentication schemes, while `AddIdentityCore` doesn't. Mainly, `AddIdentity` already calls `AddAuthentication()` for you. So when you have three calls to `AddIdentity` you are calling `AddAuthentication` three times. So while `AddIdentity` can be useful most of the times, in scenarios like this you need to use `AddIdentityCore` to avoid creating multiple auth schemes with the same name.

```
        services.AddDbContext<XenDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

        services.AddIdentityCore<Account>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
        })
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole<Guid>>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<XenDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddIdentityCore<Customer>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
        })
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole<Guid>>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<XenDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddIdentityCore<Professional>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
        })
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole<Guid>>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<XenDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Comment: That feels like you are solving the wrong problem. I would make `Account` abstract, then fix the schema via https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-type-configuration The Identity framework only needs to know about `Account`, but you'll have to create either a `Customer` or `Professional` when you register them.